# What is the equivalent purrr::map to this lapply function? R/Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This is my code

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

mylist <- c(1,2,3) %>% as.list()

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput('chart_1'),
  plotOutput('chart_2'),
  plotOutput('chart_3')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  lapply(1:3, function(x){
    output[[paste0("chart_", x)]] <- 
      renderPlot({ ggplot(gapminder::gapminder %>% filter(country == 'Chile'), aes(x = year, y = pop))+ geom_line()})
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I achieve the same result using purrr::map function instead lapply?

I am doing something like this, but I have a error message:

```
  mylist %>% map(~
                output[[glue::glue("chart_{.x}")]] <-
                  renderPlot({ ggplot(gapminder::gapminder %>% filter(country == 'Chile'),
                                      aes(x = year, y = pop))+ geom_line()})

                )
```

Comment: just change the name `lapply` to `map` and it should run. Do not change anything inside `lapply` and do not pipe into `map` since you did not pipe into `lapply`

Comment: As a side note, you are not returning anything from your `lapply` so the `purrr` equivalent should be rather `walk` then `map`. Secondly, a good old `for` loop may be even the better option here, but it has some nasty scoping issues (which can be solved).